# Can a MySQL SELECT query with "LIMIT 1" possibly return a set instead of a single value?

Tags: mysql, sql, database, cakephp

I am using CakePHP's Containable behaviour and got stuck on a weird problem. I have this:

```
'contain' => array(
            'ExhibitorTypeRequestType' => array(
                'order' => '(SELECT et.type FROM exhibitor_types AS et WHERE ExhibitorTypeRequestType.exhibitor_type_id = et.id LIMIT 1)',
                'ExhibitorType'
            )
        )
```

Which throws a SQL error:

```
Error: SQLSTATE[42S22]: Column not found: 1054 Unknown column 'SELECT et.type FROM exhibitor_types AS et WHERE ExhibitorTypeRequestType.exhibitor_type_id = et.id LIMIT 1' in 'field list'
```

Does anybody have any idea of why MySQL sees this query as a column?

**UPDATE**

I have this very similar query somewhere else in my project, also using Containable, which works perfectly:

```
'contain' => array(
            'Field',
            'User' => array(
                'UserField' => array(
                    'order' => '(SELECT f.no_order FROM fields AS f WHERE UserField.field_id = f.id LIMIT 1)'
                )
            )
        )
```

Comment: well yes i do have an idea... where do you get `ExhibitorTypeRequestType.exhibitor_type_id` ??

Comment: It isn't that MySQL has a problem with it exactly, it's that CakePHP is converting that subquery into a single column name and probably quoting it like `\`(SELECT et.type....)\``.  CakePHP must expect a column name in the `order` element, and not accept a SQL expression the way you've defined it.

Comment: (but I don't know CakePHP well enough to offer you a solution)

Comment: I have a very similar query somewhere else which works, I will update my question with it.

Comment: @JohnRuddell this is the current ExhibitorTypeRequestType object. Cake runs this query for each of these objects so they can be ordered

Comment: @MichaelBerkowski Cake does accept raw queries as input for ordering. The code I pasted in my updated answer, which works perfectly, proves that.

Comment: can you try escaping the string to put in your value? the scope of the query isn't carried to that object from what I understand

Comment: @lucasnadalutti Yes, I see that. Something is causing it to handle that query differently though. If you can cause cake to log the raw query it sends, you'll find something unusual there like a quoted subquery in the order by.

Comment: This is the raw query:

SELECT `SELECT et.type FROM exhibitor_types AS et WHERE ExhibitorTypeRequestType.exhibitor_type_id = et.id LIMIT 1`, `ExhibitorTypeRequestType`.`request_type_id` FROM `brasilgameshow11`.`exhibitor_type_request_types` AS `ExhibitorTypeRequestType` WHERE `ExhibitorTypeRequestType`.`request_type_id` = (22) ORDER BY (SELECT `et`.`type` FROM exhibitor_types AS et WHERE `ExhibitorTypeRequestType`.`exhibitor_type_id` = `et`.`id` LIMIT 1) ASC

That SELECT `SELECT etc` in the beginning is really odd, but I have no idea of what might be causing that.

Comment: I think the Very Similar piece of code has quite some differences in the structure of that array...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just figured out that if I change

```
'contain' => array(
        'ExhibitorTypeRequestType' => array(
            'order' => '(SELECT et.type FROM exhibitor_types AS et WHERE ExhibitorTypeRequestType.exhibitor_type_id = et.id LIMIT 1)',
            'ExhibitorType'
        )
    )
```

to:

```
'contain' => array(
            'ExhibitorTypeRequestType' => array(
                'order' => '(SELECT et.type FROM exhibitor_types AS et WHERE ExhibitorTypeRequestType.exhibitor_type_id = et.id LIMIT 1)',
                'ExhibitorType' => array(
                    'order' => 'type'
                )
            )
        )
```

it miraculously works! `'order' => 'type'` is absolutely irrelevant inside ExhibitorType context, it is somehow needed. Otherwise, Cake generates that bizarre SQL error.